# Remove everything before the first dot in string?

Tags: c#

How would i remove everything before the first (dot) . in a string?

For example:

```
3042. Item name 3042.
```

I want to remove 3042.

so that the string becomes

```
Item name 3042.
```

Comment: Have you tried finding where the dot appears and cutting of the preceding part?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have a look at [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx) and [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) methods.

```
var input = "3042. Item name 3042.";
var output = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(".") + 1).Trim();
```

Note that it's also safe for inputs not containing the dot.

Answer (score 4):

```
string str = "3042. Item name 3042.";
str = str.Substring(str.IndexOf('.') + 1);
```

Use string.Index of to get the position of the first `.` and then use string.Substring to get rest of the string.

Comment: The result of your code is `. Item name 3042.` and not `Item name 3042.`

Answer (score 3):

You want to remove everything before a dot inclusive the dot itself:

```
String str = "3042. Item name 3042.";
String result = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(".") + 1 ).TrimStart();
```

[`String.Substring Method` (Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx)

(note that i've used `TrimStart` to remove the empty space left because your question suggests it)

Answer (score 2):

Just for kicks, a slightly different way of doing things. Removes things up to and including the first dot

```
var testStr = @"3042. Item name 3042.";
var dotSplit = testStr.Split(new[]{'.'},2);
var results = dotSplit[1];
```

Comment: You mean `testStr.Split('.', 2);`